# Which one is best mysql or mysqli or $wpdb for wordpress plugin

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, wordpress

I have created a plugin in wordpress after updated latest version of php my mysql_connect does not work.
shows error like `PHP Fatal error occurred: Call to undefined function mysql_close()`

I know it is a PHP version problem so I need to migrate to `mysqli` but I have a doubt that which one is best `$wpdb query` or `mysqli query`

and refered that need to use `mysqli query` above php ver 4.1.3 , Should I check with

```
if(phpversion()>=4.1.3){
//use mysqli
}
else {
//use mysql
}
```

can I use like this or Is there any other way?

Comment: You shouldn't use MySql as it's outdated, you should use MySqli or PDO instead; as for $wpdb, if it's something wordpress uses, it would be recommended to use this as when wordpress is updated, that class will receive an update too

Comment: When making a WordPress plugin you *should* use the WordPress database class as it will handle all of this for you. There's nothing positive gained from creating your own connection. https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

Comment: Thank you @JessicaPartridge , you are right `$wpdb` also may get update so better go with `mysqli`

Comment: No, you should use $wpdb, it's a good thing that it gets an update as it will receive all the new security updates and bugs it may contain in previous verions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better to use `$wpdb` for the wordpress plugin

Simple and short:

`mysql_query()` = Faster!

`$wpdb->get_results()` = Safer!

But in most cases since `$wpdb` is a global object and already in the memory using it will be be as fast as `mysql_query()`.

Will this affect my performance?

It can affect for better performance changes but they would be minor changes that its just not worth it.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.overview.php

Answer (score 6):

You shouldn't use MySql as it's outdated, you should use MySqli or PDO instead; as for $wpdb, if it's something wordpress uses, it would be recommended to use this as when wordpress is updated, that class will receive an update too.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php